# Using XAMPP and phpmyadmin login page appearing when it should not be?

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

So, I changed the port numbers to 4306 and the auth_type to cookie and root and no password to true in the config.inc.php file.

However when I go to the localhost in the browser and click on myphpadmin I get a typical login page? Why... how do I bypass this? Im wanting to xfer a site online to offline to work on it and have downloaded the database.

I should have mentioned that if I hit enter (with root as username and no password) I get this error:

mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

Also the original web config file in the hosts file management has the database name, and password... to un-complicate things should I use those same parameters for the offline php config file or no db username or password...?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone looking at this. After several attempts and looking through the internet it ended up being that the firewall I am using was not allowing localhost to connect. Even though the firewall was not triggering this block in the block list... disabld the firewall and I can access myphp ..Thanks.